# Passing in string in JSON format to ajax call to server with JSON.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, json.net

I have a JSON string being sent to a server. The string is already in JSON format. Why do I have to call JSON.stringify again to have it sent successfully to the server? Successfully meaning the server hits and the value appears, but now it seems like JSON.stringify is done twice. This causes trouble when parsing it on the server? What am I doing wrong here? Why can't I just send in the JSON string?

Here is the code with the ajax call

```
    var listsJS = this.ConvertSummaryToJSON(); // Summary Page converted to json string
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({ "summary": listsJS }),
        url: GetHelper().GetVirtualDirectoryUrl() + "Reports/GenerateExcelReport"
    }).done((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log('Failed to send');
    });
```

`this.ConvertSummaryToJSON()` return the actual JSON string that looks something like this.

```
{
    "Summary": [{
        "NewBillers": []
    }, {
        "Bench": [{
            "FirstName": "Thomas",
            "LastName": "Train"
        }]
    }, {
        "SixtyDayRollOffs": [{
            "FirstName": "Michael",
            "LastName": "James"
        }]
    }, {
        "CurrentUnassignedEmployees": [{
            "Name": "Fly, Dan",
            "EmployeeTitle": "Practice Director"
        }]
    }, {
        "TotalSummaryCounts": [{
            "BenchHours": "1316",
            "EffectiveBench": "29",
            "Contributors": "37",
            "FourtyHourContributors": "14",
            "AvailableBench": "26",
            "EffectiveBillers": "79.533333"
        }]
    }]
}
```

If I make the ajax call like I did, it'll hit the server, but the JSON string will look like this

```
"{\"Summary\":[{\"NewBillers\":[]},{\"Bench\":[{\"FirstName\":\"Thomas\",  \"LastName\":\"Train\", \......."
```

If I parse this, using JSON.NET's

`JObject obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)`

I am back where I begin. With a JSON string, but represented as a JObject.
This JObject has only one value, and it's the original JSON string that I started with.

So I'm messing up where I'm sending it. It should be sent at as a JSON string, not a `JSON.stringify()` version of a JSON string.

I've altering the ajax call to just have

`data: {"summary": listsJS}`

but this causes the server to throw a `500 Internal Server error` with a response of `Invalid JSON primitive: summary`

How can I just pass in the JSON string straight from `listsJS` without having to `JSON.stringify()` it again to pass it to the server?

If I use just `data: listsJS` then it will hit the server, but the parameter in the method on the server will receive a null value.

Here is what the server code looks like, maybe it'll help.

```
public ActionResult GenerateExcelReport(string summary)
{
    var a = ExportUtility.CreateExcelSheet(summary); // <-- this just returns a literal string "Message from server"
    return Json(a, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `data: listsJS,` ?

Comment: @JasonP Yes, If I call it like that then it will hit the server, but the parameter the method on the server will receive will be null.

Answer (score 0):

I note quite sure if I understood all your questions correctly, but here we go:

(1) `{ foo: "bar" }` is **NOT** a JSON string. It's a JavaScript Object. This is the coreesponding JSON representation `'{"foo":"bar"}'`. They both look very similar because (I think you know that, but just to be sure) JSON stands for JavaScriptObjectNotation. It is just a convention for representing in a "string" form.

(2) You do not have to stringify your object when you use `$.ajax`. As the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) states: it will be "converted to a query string, if not already a string." Meaning it will end up in the form data of your XHR as a string anyway.

(3) The reason you (or jQuery) stringifies the object for you is that the HTTP-Protocol is text-based. Otherwise it would be hard to use it with different technologies. So your server only gets a "text message" and has to parse the form data back to whatever notation it understands (together with additional data that for example tells the receiver of the XHR that this is a POST).

Comment: My string is a valid JSON string, it just prints to the console without the quotes. If I just call `data: listJS` it should already work because listJS is a valid JSON string. The server will get hit, but the data in the method parameter on the server will be null.

Answer (score 0):

There are some unclear things in your question but I'm going to take a guess here and say that your object is getting `JSON.stringify`d twice.

The `this.ConvertSummaryToJSON()` return value you posted looks like a JavaScript **object** not a JSON string but I assume that was a mistake because the object keys *do* look like it was stringified.

So here's the thing, when you're making an ajax call with `data: JSON.stringify({ 'summary': listsJS })`, the object you have passed to `JSON.stringify` contains a key `summary` with a *string* value pointed to by `listsJS`. When this is serialized, sent to your server and deserialized, the result is the same thing you sent: a string! If you were to deserialized that string once again you would have your required object.

Just using `data: {"summary": listsJS}` will not work for the same reason, you are sending a string and jQuery has no way of knowing that that string is a JSON serialized object, so it will happily serialize that string for you.

What you need to do is to just return the relevant object from your `this.ConvertSummaryToJSON` function instead of a JSON string. You can then send the data with `data: { 'summary': listsJS }`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since `this.ConvertSummaryToJSON()` returns a JSON string, Converting it to a Javascript object will work fine, but when I then either stringify then pass it, or just pass it to the ajax call it will not work. Stringifying it then attaching it will cause the value to appear null on the server, and just attaching it will throw `Invalid JSON primitive: summary`

Comment: Can you please check with the following:
`data: JSON.parse(listsJS)`